# RSSI value using MicroPython in NodeMCU ESP8266

Tags: networking, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu, micropython

How to get the RSSI value of the WLAN device connected to WiFi of my NodeMCU device using MicroPython? Actually I tried the following code but I'm getting an error:

```
>>> sta_if.ifconfig()         
('192.168.1.103', '255.255.255.0', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1')

>>> sta_if.rssi()        
Traceback (most recent call last):        
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>        
AttributeError: 'WLAN' object has no attribute 'rssi'
```

I don't know what I should do to get the RSSI value of the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WLAN class documentation](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/library/network.html#class-wlan):

> **wlan.scan()**
>
> Scan for the available wireless networks.
>
> Scanning is only possible on STA interface. Returns list of tuples with the information about WiFi access points:
>
> (ssid, bssid, channel, RSSI, authmode, hidden)